# Which one is dedicated hosting?

Tags: web-hosting

A dedicated hosting is a type of Internet hosting in which the client leases an entire server not shared with anyone. From wikipedia [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_hosting_service)

My question can I place multiple website in a dedicated hosting Service? Then also it known as dedicated hosting or something else?

1. if IIS shares multiple website .
2. if IIS can only be dedicated to a single web site

which one we can say a dedicated hosting ? condition 1 or 2

Note: My question is not about dedicated servers.

Comment: Your question does not make alot of sense.  Maybe try rewording it.

Comment: are you looking to be a reseller or have a site hosted?

Comment: No need to ask this again: http://serverfault.com/questions/57899/which-one-is-dedicated-hosting

Comment: Manni: 404 on that page.

Comment: Good!

Answer (score 7):

A dedicated hosting service generally relates to the server being dedicated to you and not shared with others.

In this case the server is generally yours to do wjhat you want with, i.e. hosting as many or as few sites as you wish (witin the servers capability).

Comment: +1. As such has nothing to do with the Setup of Websites on the Server, which is the criteria give nby the poster.

Answer (score 1):

If you are renting the entire server you can host as many websites as you want on it.  Your only limit will be that if you need SSL certs for each site, the hosting company will probably charge you for extra public IP addresses as each site using SSL requires its own public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but I'll give it a shot.  If you purchase dedicated hosting from a provider, the service would be dedicated for you.  You have one box dedicated to whatever your purpose.  If you were then reselling webhosting to other parties it would not be dedicated to them, because resources would be shared between all those sites.

Answer (score 0):

On a dedicated host, you are the only person on the machine.  You should be able to host multiple sites.  A dedicated host says the you will be the only one on the machine

Answer (score 0):

My employer bought their own server hardware and has send it to a special hosting company to be included in their server park. Because it's our own server, we can do with it whatever we like and we're using it to host multiple sites. It is out machine and it will stay ours forever.
The hosting company makes sure it keeps running, doing regular maintenance and checkups and they provide the power and Internet connection for our box. They take care of the hardware architecture and we're responsible for the software components.

However, there are also dedicated hosting solutions where you don't buy but rent a host. While this is less expensive, it also allows the hosting company to add any other restrictions to the hardware/software. For example, they could restrict you to just a certain operating system, database or virus scanner. In return, they will take care of some of the software on the system, keeping it up-to-date and doing the required maintenance and repairs to the software.

In general, there are lots of different kinds of dedicated hosting but in general it means that the hosting company is mostly responsible for the hardware while you yourself are more responsible for the software. One advantage for the host is that if your software crashes the system, it would only crash your system. With shared hosting, one site could force all 300 other sites on the same host to go down crashing and burning.

Answer (score -2):

In Dedicated server  the user gets his or her own Web server and gains full control over it. However, the user typically does not own the server. Another type of Dedicated hosting is Self-Managed or Unmanaged. This is usually the least expensive for Dedicated plans. The user has full administrative access to the server, which means the client is responsible for the security and maintenance of his own dedicated server.

Dedicated server hosting enables users with the freedom of choosing their own software. Thus, customers who have expanded their shared hosting limits, still require more and now opting for dedicated web server hosting. It is very much truth that a dedicated server hosting is very flexible as the server administration and provides with the best services by the website hosting companies. A dedicated server hosting benefits like reliability, flexibility, total control and gives complete security without having to work for it.

Comment: Sounds like marketing copy